# Raise unhandled C exception in Python

Tags: python, c, windows, exception

I am extending a Python 2.7.5 app for Windows. The app uses [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to install a Python function that is called when an unhandled C exception occurs:

```
@ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.wintypes.LONG, PEXCEPTION_POINTERS)
def crashHandler(exceptionInfo):
    # Some code that deals with the unhandled C exception...
...
windll.kernel32.SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(crashHandler)
```

(I will give the code for `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS` below because I don't think it's relevant for the purpose of this question.)

In its original form, `crashHandler` does some logging and shuts down the process. I have observed it deal with unhandled exceptions a few times, so I'm pretty confident that `crashHandler` is correctly installed as an UnhandledExceptionFilter.

I have made some modifications to `crashHandler` and would now like to test it. To do this, my idea would be to programmatically raise a C exception that should then be handled by `crashHandler`. I tried the following:

```
>>> windll.kernel32.RaiseException(5, 0, 0, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
>>> windll.kernel32.RaiseException(6, 0, 0, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

So the exception is immediately caught by the Python interpreter, hence does not get propagated to my `crashHandler`.

How can I either a) disable Python's exception handling or b) programmatically raise a C exception that is not caught by Python's exception handling mechanism and gets propagated to my `crashHandler`?

---

Here's the code for `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS`:

```
from ctypes import Structure
import ctypes
EXCEPTION_MAXIMUM_PARAMETERS = 15
class EXCEPTION_RECORD(Structure):
    pass
PEXCEPTION_RECORD = ctypes.wintypes.POINTER(EXCEPTION_RECORD)
EXCEPTION_RECORD._fields_ = [
    ('ExceptionCode',           ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
    ('ExceptionFlags',          ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
    ('ExceptionRecord',         PEXCEPTION_RECORD),
    ('ExceptionAddress',        ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID),
    ('NumberParameters',        ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
    ('ExceptionInformation',    ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID * EXCEPTION_MAXIMUM_PARAMETERS),
]
class EXCEPTION_POINTERS(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('ExceptionRecord', PEXCEPTION_RECORD),
                ('ContextRecord', ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID)]
PEXCEPTION_POINTERS = ctypes.wintypes.POINTER(EXCEPTION_POINTERS)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do `crashHandler(the_arguments)`? These things should all be mocked when doing unit-testing.

Comment: Of course, that's a possibility. But I want to test under more realistic circumstances. Maybe an unhandled C exception leaves the Python interpreter in a brittle state? Those are the things I would like to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windll module automatically catches windows SEH exceptions which occur in calls, and converts them to WindowsError python exceptions. Hence they are not unhandled exceptions.

You need to use an API which doesn't have such a good wrapper.

Your best bet is to use a C extension module which causes an access violation by dereferencing a random pointer (or null).